# Не выполняется условие запроса

Tags: mysql, pdo, like

Есть функция поиска, которая выбирает условия поиска, исходя из значения $select. Но Это не работает, выполнятся всегда поиск по значению $select == 'all'. Сама функция:

```
function magazine_search($query, $select){

    if($select == 'all') {
        $query = clear($query);
        try {
            $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8', HOST, DB);
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, USER, PASS);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "<p>Запрос на выборку данных из бызы не прошёл. Напишите об этом администратору <a href='mailto:admin@torawhite.ru'>admin@torawhite.ru</a>.</p><br>ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_title LIKE :query1 OR article_description LIKE :query2 OR article_text LIKE :query3';
        $data = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $data->bindValue(':query1', '%' . $query . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data->bindValue(':query2', '%' . $query . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data->bindValue(':query3', '%' . $query . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data->execute();
        $result_search = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (count($result_search) < 1) {
            $result_search['notfound'] = "<div class='search_title'><span>По Вашему запросу статей не найдено</span></div>";
        }
        return $result_search;
    }elseif ($select == 1) {
        $query = clear($query);
        try {
            $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8', HOST, DB);
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, USER, PASS);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "<p>Запрос на выборку данных из бызы не прошёл. Напишите об этом администратору <a href='mailto:admin@torawhite.ru'>admin@torawhite.ru</a>.</p><br>ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_title LIKE :query1 OR article_description LIKE :query2 OR article_text LIKE :query3 AND article_par_id = :article_par_id';
        $data = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $data->bindValue(':query1', '%' . $query . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data->bindValue(':query2', '%' . $query . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data->bindValue(':query3', '%' . $query . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $data->bindValue(':article_par_id', (int)$select, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $data->execute();
        $result_search = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (count($result_search) < 1) {
            $result_search['notfound'] = "<div class='search_title'><span>По Вашему запросу статей не найдено</span></div>";
        }
        return $result_search;
    }
}
```

дальше перечисляются ещё условия, но также в зависимости от цифры в переменной $select

Comment: проверяли чему = значение переменной $select в начале функции ?

Comment: vanZakirov вывел его в результатах поиска, всё совпадает. Значение передаётся массивом $_GET. В начале контроллера приравниваю - $select = $_GET['select']

Comment: Разобрался - нужно условие с like заключить в скобки $sql = 'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE (article_title LIKE :query1 OR article_description LIKE :query2 OR article_text LIKE :query3) AND article_par_id = :article_par_id';